# how to user login via social networks and retrieve the profile details

Tags: authentication, facebook-login, social-networking, google-signin

We developing hybrid mobile application in that having login,register and dashboard pages.

In Login page **user login to app via multiple social networks** like **Facebook,twitter,google**. and **retrieve profile information** for a user.

Any one please guide/suggest me how to approach above requirement step by step. if any have sample code application please provide me.

what ever i develop the sample project that code also i posted please find it and guide me what we have to do next step

[i create facebook sdk in facebook developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/821578904640078/?platform=web)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>LoginSN</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <!--
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
        -->
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId : '821578904640078',
                    xfbml : true,
                    version : 'v2.6'
                });
            };

            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
                }
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

    </head>


    <body style="display: none;">

        <div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                <label for="text">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unL">
                <label for="text">Password:</label><input type="password" name="text" id="pwdL">
                <a href="#dashboardPage" data-role="button" id="buttonLn">LOGIN</a>
                <a href="#registrationPage" data-role="button" id="buttonRe">REGISRASTION</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" id="buttonF">via Facebook Login</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" id="buttonG">via Google Login</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" id="buttonT">via Twitter Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="registrationPage">
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                <label for="text">Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unR">
                <label for="text">DOB:</label><input type="date" name="text" id="pwdR">
                <label for="text">Contact No:</label><input type="number" name="text" id="pwdR">
                <label for="text">Email ID:</label><input type="email" name="text" id="pwdR">
                <label for="text">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unR">
                <label for="text">Password:</label><input type="password" name="text" id="pwdR"> 
                <a href="#loginPage" data-role="button" id="buttonR">Registered</a>
    </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="dashboardPage">
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">

            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Read about OAuth/OAuth2.Your question is really broad, it´s hard to answer you without writing a whole blog post. Maybe you can smallen you question after reading

Comment: yes kabaehr, i am using OAuth2 to login my application via google

Comment: And what is your exact problem? You can login via Google but you don´t know how to retrieve user info?

Comment: yes i am not retrive the user info and also i am not able to login through facebook